# OCR not working to extract loan details from bank loan letter using ML Kit (Firebase or Google), any alternatives?

Tags: ocr, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

how to get all details from the bank loan letter using Ocr  (including loan amount, loan type, loan number, etc )

I try the ML kit but doesn't work, is there any way to get text in key-value pair (Like Loan Amount - 0000/-)